# How does one do 3D subsurface laser engraving for relatively translucent minerals?

Tags: radiation, laser, glass

3D Subsurface Laser Engraving works for clear glasses like Schott BK7 and B9 Borosilicate Glass.

How does one do the same for relatively translucent minerals?

I have read research papers on using lasers for tattoo removal and cancer radiation therapy.

However, I want to know how the laser's focal point can be fixed with precision inside the translucent materials to properly engrave.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with good optics you can focus inside the optically transparent material with micron precision.  I've done this to create penny shaped cracks in lexan for ultrasonic studies.  For this I used a Q-switched YAG laser.  To be precise you really need a high quality gaussian beam coming from the laser.  Then mount the focusing optics on a motorized stage and you can create any pattern you like.  In the case of tattoo removal you don't even need to focus the beam since all you're doing is breaking down the dyes just below the surface.  Another option used in microscopy is to use multiple beams each of which is below the damage threshold but when focused simultaneously can create quite high fluences.